# Term Structure and short rates

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

If I have a term structure/yield curve given by:
$$f(t, T) = f(0, T) + σ^2t(T − \frac{t}{2}) + σB_t $$

and want to find the short/spot rate $r_t$, is this simply:

$$f(t,t) = f(0,t) + \sigma^2t(t-\frac{t}{2}) + \sigma B_t$$

Can anything further be done?

Comment: That is the definition of the spot rate.

Comment: Is this as far is we go here?

Comment: Yes.  That is the short rate.  What is the application?  Are you simulating the spot rate?  What model is this?

Comment: What the application is... I am not to sure. This is just an exercise from my notes. It has a follow-up exercise which says to write the equation for forward rates in terms of the short rate.

This confuses me, since I thought $f(t,T)$ was the forward rate.. and how can this be expressed in terms of a spot rate?